# My HTML code is not being read on Javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I'm doing a quote generator in Javascript in which the quote generates on click.

The code looks like this:

```
$("#getQuote").on("click", function(){
var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * quote.length));

   $("#theQuote").html(quote[i] <\br> person[i]);
});
```

I'm trying to make a line break between the quote and the person who made the quote but it doesn't seem the recognize any code after `quote[i]`.

I've also tried adding `\n` to the strings in my array for example:

```
var quote = ['"With great power, comes great responsibility." \n- Uncle Ben'];
```

but somehow `\n` is not read whereas the rest of the quote is.

Comment: Use `<br>` instead of `<\br>`

Comment: change this   `$("#theQuote").html(quote[i] <br> person[i]);`  to  `$("#theQuote").html(quote[i] +'<br>'+ person[i]);`

Comment: Is it inserting the actual text "\n" or is it just not showing anything? Because by default, HTML wraps all consecutive whitespace into a single space.

Comment: @ParagJadhav did you mean `<br/>` instead of `<\br>`?

Comment: user $("#theQuote").html(quote[i] + '<\br>' + person[i]) because its takes string only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st `$("#theQuote").html(quote[0] + '<br>' + person[0]);` anything without wrap by `'` or `"` are either number or variable, and `.html` take string as html, so you need concate them use `+`

2nd this way will also work, `var quote = ['"With great power, comes great responsibility." <br> - TEST_1 Uncle Ben'];`

```js
var quote = ['"With great power, comes great responsibility." <br> - TEST_1 Uncle Ben'];
var person = ['TEST_2 Uncle Ben'];

$("#getQuote").on("click", function() {
  //var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * quote.length));

  $("#theQuote").html(quote[0] + '<br>' + person[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="getQuote">getQuote</button>

<br><br>
<div id="theQuote">N/A</div>
```

Comment: I somehow thought .html passed html code. Thank you for clarifying that it's in the form of strings and requires inverted commas.

Answer (score -1):

Change `<\br>` to `<br>` or `<br />`. This is according to the [HTML5 standards](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp).